# What library does the _convert method in python belong to

Tags: python

I received a python file containing the following line of code

```
 logistic_regressor.predict_proba(_convert(X, type(var1)))
```

It worked alright so far so never came to my notice. Recently it started throwing an error saying

> Unresolved reference '_convert'

`_convert` doesn't look like a standard python function.

My guess is that is that the aim is to convert `X` to the type of `var1`, but I am not sure what library it is a part of or if this is something recently deprecated (could not find any documentation and a google search yielded nothing).

What library is `_convert` from?

EDIT: I took a look again and it seems like the method that contained this line of code was never invoked which is why the error was never thrown. So I could just ignore it, but I'm hoping that someone has seen _convert used in this context.

Comment: If it worked, either you or the original author defined a `_convert` function, or there was an import like `from my_library import _convert`

Comment: If _convert is coming from some library, the time it worked, you could go back in git to see the dependencies, install them and check in the virtual env site-packages where its defined

Comment: @crissal it does not look like either of those was done

Comment: @Cloverr Source control was a good suggestion. Thanks